# JDBC interface object in java

Tags: java, jdbc

If interfaces cannot be instantiated, then how can we create objects of `Statement` interface in JDBC?

I went to the Oracle Java documentation, it shows:

```
public interface Statement
extends Wrapper, AutoCloseable
```

I guess the code below is creating a reference variable, but I need a proper explanation that I can't find anywhere.

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
```

If it is an interface, then how can it define method bodies? Obviously it isn't a class.

Comment: Interfaces are basically like bones, they are plain bones that sets apart a  human bone from a tiger bone for instance. When you add muscles, tissues, blood vessels, skin, color, declare some peculiar actions/ behavior like walk, eat, think etc is what you basically do when implementing an interface... This is a generic interface concept.

Comment: All you can tell from the code snipped `Statement stmt = con.createStatement();` is that some class that implements the connection interface gets its createStatement method called and returns another class that implements the Statement interface. What the actual im plementation classes behind these interfaces is is uknown and in this context not important.

Comment: Thank you, @OHGODSPIDERS, you made it a bit clear also from the logical point of view. i am kind of intermediate in Java, but i was wondering from some kind of description that you provided. Obviously i'll need to do some research and debug some programs to completely understand it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, `con.createStatement()` will be returning an instance of some class which implements the `Statement` interface.

`con` is presumably a concrete instance of a class which implements `java.sql.Connection`, and that concrete implementation of `Connection` defines what type of `Statement` it should return.

The easiest way to see this would be to run your code with a debugger, and you'll be able to see the actual type that `stmt` is at runtime. That type will be something that implements `Statement`.

To give a very simple example of how this might work for an imaginary database called "SomeDatabase", you have the `Statement` interface that you've shown above:

```
public interface Statement extends Wrapper, AutoCloseable
```

and the `Connection` interface:

```
public interface Connection extends Wrapper, AutoCloseable
```

And let's say `con` is an instance of a concrete class called `SomeDatabaseConnection`, which implements the method `createStatement` because that's required by the `Connection` interface. The implementation of `createStatement` returns an instance of a concrete class implementing `Statement` that's specific to "SomeDatabase":

```
public class SomeDatabaseConnection implements Connection {
    public Statement createStatement() {
        return new SomeDatabaseStatement();
    }
}
```

Now we can say:

```
Connection con = new SomeDatabaseConnection();
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
```

Hopefully you can see here that the actual concrete class that's returned is an instance of `SomeDatabaseStatement`, which implements `Statement`.

The whole point of all this is that the details can be hidden away from your application code; it doesn't matter whether your `Connection` or `Statement` are provided by Oracle, MySQL or "SomeDatabase", the functionality that they provide is guaranteed by the interfaces that you develop against, so you can easily switch out one database for another without changing your own code at all.

**Terminology**

Although the actual concrete class of `stmt` is some specific class (`SomeDatabaseStatement` in my silly example), we can still say it "is a Statement", because it complies to all the requirements of the `Statement` interface.

Additionally, because the `Statement` interface extends `Wrapper` and `AutoCloseable`, we can say that `stmt` "is a Wrapper" and "is an AutoCloseable", because we know that it must comply with the requirements of both those interfaces too.

Your line:

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
```

Could be written as:

```
MyDatabaseStatement stmt = con.createStatement();
```

but would also be just as correct written as:

```
Wrapper stmt = con.createStatement();
```

or

```
AutoCloseable stmt = con.createStatement();
```

The obvious next question is which of those should we choose? The simple answer to that is whichever gives you all the functionality you need, and no more.

In this specific example, for most cases that will be `Statement`, because the `Statement` interface gives you all the useful methods for interacting with a database. However, if, for some reason, the only method you needed to call was `close()`, which is defined in the `AutoCloseable` interface, then it would probably be better to use `AutoCloseable` instead of `Statement`.

To learn more about why this is good, read about the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).

Comment: Thank you very much! I got that now, you and your explanation are awesome. can't find better answer than this. So just to confirm, the stmt is actually object but not of Statement interface itself, but some subclass that implements it?

Comment: @AniketKariya yes, the type of `stmt` will be a class that implements the `Statement` interface

Comment: @AniketKariya, that's right - see my edit to add a little bit about terminology though - hope it doesn't just end up confusing you!